# eclipse plugin application to Zk application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, command, handler, zk

I'm working on creating a `Zk` application from an `eclipse plugin` and I'm searching for how I can reproduce the behavior of the `Commands` and the `Handlers` that we can find in the Menu of the `plugin application`.They defined in the `plugin.xml` file into the `extension point`. [image: The commands that I want to reproduce]

I want to know if there is a way to link a `Zk component` with those `commands`?

Comment: This is rather unclear. plugin.xml commands and handlers are only for plugins which are going to run as part of Eclipse and have nothing to do with web applications.

Comment: I know that why I'm confused. I want to reproduce those behavior in the web application.